# Rounding the decimal in different time points

Tags: r, rounding, distribution

I have generated a sample of size 100 from a standard normal distribution by using `rnorm` function. I would like to round the numbers by following criteria.
if number is between 0 and 1, it will be rounded in 1 decimal point. e.g

```
0.123 -> 0.1
0.456 -> 0.5
0.98 -> 1
```

and if a number is greater than 1 then it will be rounded as:

```
2.34 -> 2
4.98 -> 5
4.4 -> 4
```

Can you guide me how I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean (-1, 1) or (0, 1) not equal to abs( (-1, 1) )? Since the normal distribution produces positive and negative numbers, I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the base-10 log to set the rounding level:

```
set.seed(1); x = rnorm(100) # example
y = round(x, log10(abs(x)) < 0)

head(cbind(x,y)) # check results

              x    y
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.6
[2,]  0.1836433  0.2
[3,] -0.8356286 -0.8
[4,]  1.5952808  2.0
[5,]  0.3295078  0.3
[6,] -0.8204684 -0.8
```

*How it works.* R treats TRUE/FALSE like 1/0 when it needs to, so...

- When `log10(abs(x)) < 0`, it will round to one decimal
- When `log10(abs(x)) >= 0`, it will round to zero decimals

Answer (score 3):

Here is another inspired by @Franks solution:

```
round(x, abs(x) < 1)
```

The rounding will move between 0 and 1 with the test `abs(x) < 1`. This will work for values that have a magnitude less than 1 or are in the interval (-1, 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ifelse(x>=0 & x<=1, round(x, 1), round(x))
```

EDIT:
or this in general:

```
ifelse(abs(x)<1, round(x, 1), round(x))
```

Comment: Your criterion should use abs(x), probably, since the OP is looking at "a sample [...] from a standard normal distribution"

Comment: I could use `abs(x)` in place of `x` but I managed to make it based on the given criteria

Answer (score 1):

The `ifelse` function should do this pretty easily.

```
x <- c(0.123, 0.456, 0.98, 2.34, 4.98, 4.4)
ifelse(abs(x) < 1.0, round(x, 1), round(x, 0))
[1] 0.1 0.5 1.0 2.0 5.0 4.0
```

But, if you don't want the decimal `x.0` after your integers, then as @PierreLaFortune mentioned in the comment, it is harder because you can't mix types in an atomic vector.  Like he said, you can coerce to a character:

```
> as.character(ifelse(x <= 1.0, round(x, 1), round(x, 0)))
[1] "0.1" "0.5" "1"   "2"   "5"   "4"
```